# Converting between similar enums from different services

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm implementing a service that exposes an enum through a gRPC api.
This service also calls another gRPC API that defines the same enum.

Both enums are defined in different packages (autogenerated code).

How can I seamlessly convert between them in the Go programming language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's presume we have the following enum types

- `Select`
- `Choose`

### Type Conversion - [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DBRi4GWGttE)

If the underlying types & values are the same, then you can use type conversions

```golang
type Select int32
type Choose int32

const SelectCat Select = 0
const ChooseCat Choose = 0

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Choose(SelectCat) == ChooseCat)
}
```

### Mapping Types - [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wKzD-2znDzZ)

In all situations, you can use a map to convert between the 2 Enums

```golang
type Select int32
type Choose string

const SelectCat Select = 0
const ChooseCat Choose = "cat"

var selectAToChooseOne = map[SelectA]ChooseOne{
  SelectACat: ChooseOneCat,
}

func SelectToChoose(selected Select) (Choose, bool) {
    chosen, ok := selectToChoose[selected]

    return chosen, ok
}

func ChooseToSelect(chosen Choose) (Select, bool) {
    for s, c := range selectToChoose {
        if c == chosen {
            return s, true
        }
    }

    return Select(-1), false
}

func main() {
  chosen, ok := SelectToChoose(SelectCat)
  _ = ok // do something with ok

  fmt.Println(chosen == ChooseCat)
}
```

In this case lookups going from `Select` kinds to `Choose` kinds will be quicker. This is because `SelectToChoose` directly uses the underlying mapping to lookup values. `ChooseToSelect` however iterates over each key/value (Select/Choose) pair to find the correct match. I've added an `ok` to these methods, but that isn't a requirement